# How I code a wrapper that lies to an app running inside it?

Tags: windows, winapi

I own a laptop with nVidia Optimus

I tried everything to get rid of it, or make it work, and it refuses to work.

One problem in particular, is that when the WinAPI is called with information about the hardware (for example queries with capabilities, device-id, device name, and so on), apps always get the information for the integrated Intel card, that is terrible, and don't exactly match the nVidia card in capabilities either, this make some games and apps misbehave or crash.

I was wondering, can I somehow override those WinAPI calls, and make them lie? For example when the app asks about GPU Device-ID, I tell to it that it is a arbitrary device I want.

Bonus question: Can this also be applied to ASM calls, like CPUID and RDTSC? Many older games rely on those... also the Intel Compiler infamously made to work with only P4 tend to treat new (Core i7 of any generation) CPUs as AMD, and choose crap code paths.

EDIT: Some people are misunderstanding what I want to code.

I want to make a launcher app to workaround a common nVidia Optimus bug, like those apps to make games borderless, or to make them use a different more compatible version of DirectX than their original.

nVidia Optimus works (usually, it can be done differently) by the machine having a integrated Intel Chip, and a nVidia Discrete GPU, the computer treats the DGPU as a sort of video-coprocessor, the actual video chip is always the Intel video chip, but when Optimus kicks in, the Hardware Accelerated rendering is passed to the DGPU, that after finishings its work, copy the results into Intel's chip framebuffer, that finally show it on the screens.

The bug in this implementation, is that it never considered what happens when an app queries about the video capabilities, because the video chip is always the Intel one, any queries get a reply related to the Intel one, even if the chip that will actually receive the draw calls in this app is the nVidia one.

As result, any mismatched DX or OGL extensions between the GPUs can cause bugs or crashes, programs may assume wrong things about the available computing power and memory, may have timing problems, and so on.

I've been fighting with this tech for years, and found no practical solution, this idea is my "final stand" idea, make a "Optimus Launcher" app, that allows you to launch any game with Optimus and it will work, hopefully without ugly hacks like disabling Secure Boot (I disabled Secure Boot to play Age of Decadence, in machines with Optimus AoD, and other Torque3D games, don't work if Secure Boot is enabled, I have no idea why).

Comment: On my computer, Control Panel/Nvidia Control Panel has some options under "Manage 3D settings."  In particular, it lets me specify which adapter to use for a given program.

Comment: You need to fix your system setup, so that applications can discover the dedicated GPU. On my laptop, I have a Core i7 with integrated graphics and a dedicated GPU. Games will pick the GPU for rendering. Lying won't help you either: At some point the application will have to create a rendering device. You'd have to somehow redirect device creation to fit your lies.

Comment: The applications are creating a nVidia rendering device, but getting information for the intel device when they query, thus they are getting mismatched capabilities and are crapping out. For example: SimCity 4 launches with the GPU according to nVidia tools, but when it dumps the configuration info it detected, it only detected the intel card, 32mb of VRAM, etc... Also new games made with Ogre3D or Torque3D don't let me change the resolution and whatnot because they only see the Intel card, even when the GPU is actually rendering. This is a side effect of how Optimus work

Comment: Optimus work by the Intel being the actual video chip, and the GPU being only used to calculate 3D and pasting data in the Intel's Framebuffer, it is obvious that if an app query the video chip, it will land on the Intel's, not on nVidia's.

Comment: Why people are downvoting and close voting? Care to explain?

Answer (score 1):

You can hook WinAPI calls and make them do what ever you like but it's nothing which is implemented easily. Furthermore I guess that some anti virus programs will get very nervous if you application is doing stuff like that...

Take a look at this article which is a good start: [API hooking revealed](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed)